# javascript for loop unexpected behaviour

Tags: javascript, loops

I have couple of questions about the javascript for loop.

First question:

```
for (i=0; i<=2; i++) {;}
console.log(i);
```

Output is 3. Shouldn't it be 2?

Second question:

```
for (var i=0; i<=2; i++) {
    setTimeout(function(){console.log(i);}, i*1000);
}
```

Timeouts are set correctly: 0, 1000 and 2000. But the output is 3,3,3 (should be 0, 1, 2). Does this mean the delayed functions are executed **after** the loop exits? Why?

What should I read to understand all this mysterious javascript stuff?

Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**First question:**

No because the `i` variable is incremented *after* the last successful iteration, then the condition is checked and it evaluates to `false` so the loop ends.

The `for` statement is composed by:

```
for ([initialExpression]; [condition]; [incrementExpression])
  statement
```

And it is executed in the following steps:

1. The `initialExpression` is evaluated at the start
2. The `condition` is evaluated, if it evaluates to `false`, the loop ends, if it evaluates to `true`, the statement is evaluated.
3. Evaluate the statement.
4. The `incrementExpression` is evaluated, go to step 2.

**Second question:**

The function is executed asynchronously **after** the loop has ended, at this time as you know `i` contains `3`.

The common workaround for this is to use a function to preserve the value of the looping variable on each iteration, for example:

```
for (var i=0; i<=2; i++) {
  (function (i) {
    setTimeout(function(){console.log(i);}, i*1000);
  })(i);
}
```

Comment: superb. the function inside function idea from here helped me pass "current" value of a changing variable into onreadystatechange function for an XMLHttpRequest. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

That's because your console.log instruction is outside of the for loop.

This will print it up to two as you intended:

```
for (i=0; i<=2; i++) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

For loops will only repeatedly execute what you type within the parentheses. That's why console.log was executed only once.

Source: http://www.kompulsa.com/a-guide-to-for-loops-in-javascript/