# Javascript loop reference

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [javascript for loop unexpected behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170589/javascript-for-loop-unexpected-behaviour)

I'am programming in node.js and i run into a small problem  what is caused by some strange pass by reference problem.

i use the following code:

```
for(j in groups){
  console.log(j, somefunction(groups[j]))
}
```

inside of the function some funky things are done with the data but afterwards i get the following as result:

```
3 data
3 data
3 data
3 data
3 data
3 data
```

instead of

```
1 data
2 data
3 data
4 data
5 data
6 data
```

but it keeps the correct amount of result..

Comment: Two things: 1. Your quoted code does not do that (you lost something in the simplification for the question -- easy to do!), and 2. JavaScript does not have any form of pass by reference. All arguments are passed by *value*. Objects (including functions) are referred to by reference, which has nothing to do with "pass by reference".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it this way :-

```
    for(var j in groups)
    {
        //Your code
    }
```

j is not returning the correct value because you have assigned j at a global scope. Hope this help!

Comment: We don't know that there isn't a `var j;` above the code he just hasn't quoted, nor that (if there isn't) j is ever used for anything else (e.g., it could be an implicit global without actually being the problem). It would take a very specific bit of unseen code to set `j` to exactly what's quoted. Occams's razor says...not so much.

Answer (score 1):

Your quoted code doesn't do what you've listed, you probably lost something simplifying it for the question.

This code would have the effect you're describing, though:

```
for(j in groups){
  doSomething(function() {
    // Callback for `doSomething`
    console.log(j, somefunction(groups[j]));
  });
}
```

Note that now I'm creating a function (a callback for whatever `doSomething` does), not just *calling* one.

The reason that happens is that the function being created has an *enduring reference* to the `j` variable (and everything else in the execution context), not a *copy* of it as of when the function was created. It's called a *closure* over that execution context. So your loop runs, a series of calls to `doSomething` start a series of things, and then later when the callbacks are called, `j` is 3 and so it's the same for all of them.

The usual solution is to create functions that close over something that won't change before they get called, like this:

```
for(j in groups){
  doSomething(makeCallback(j));
}

function makeCallback(jarg) {
    return function() {
        console.log(jarg, somefunction(groups[jarg]));
    };
}
```

Now, we're using `jarg` in our callback, rather than `j`. Because `jarg` is part of the context of the call to `makeCallback`, it doesn't change between when we create the function and when it's called later.

Another way you can bind data to functions is to use [`Function#bind`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.5) (which *effectively* creates a closure in the background), which is an ES5 feature available in NodeJS because the V8 engine has it. Here's how that would look:

```
for(j in groups){
  doSomething(function(jarg) {
    // Callback for `doSomething`
    console.log(jarg, somefunction(groups[jarg]));
  }.bind(this, j)); // <== Note the bind
}
```

or less confusingly (and quite possibly more efficiently):

```
for(j in groups){
  doSomething(handler.bind(this, j));
}

function handler(jarg) {
  // Callback for `doSomething`
  console.log(jarg, somefunction(groups[jarg]));
}
```

More about closures:

- [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)

Answer (score 0):

ive found if i use 
    var j = 0

```
for(i in groups){
j = i
```

the system does work how but it's not the best awnser