# Javascript: connection.query function is breaking my for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops

I commented the values on the first (and only) execution of my for loop.  It doesn't seem to matter what I do... after connection.query my for loop is always given a value that escapes the loop.  No idea why.  I can provide more examples.  Anyone know what might be going on and how I can get around the problem?
Here is a snippet of code that has this problem.
The mysql plugin for node.js i'm using is here

https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql

```
for (j=0;j<rows[i].movelimit;j++){
            //j=0
               sql2="SELECT x, y, land FROM map WHERE collision = 0 AND x>"+(lastX-55)+" AND x<"+(lastX+55)+" AND y>"+(lastY-55)+" AND y<"+(lastY+55)+" AND land='"+rows[i].land+"'"+restrictions;
               connection.query(sql2, function(err, move, fields) {
            //j=rows[i]movelimit
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be an asynchronous callback. Therefore, your loop variable `j` which is out of the scope of the callback function, will always evaluate to the last value it got assigned before the loop ended. See also [javascript for loop unexpected behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3170589/1048572) or [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/1048572).

Use a [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/111102/1048572):

```
function getCallbackFn(index) {
    return function(err, move, fields) {
        ....
        // "index" will always point to the function argument
    };
}
for (j=0;j<rows[i].movelimit;j++) {
    var sql2 = ...
    connection.query(sql2, getCallbackFn(j));
}
```

Shorter, inline IEFE:

```
for (j=0;j<rows[i].movelimit;j++) (function(j){
    var sql2 = ...
    connection.query(sql2, function(err, move, fields) {
        ....
        // "j" points to the function argument
    });
})(j);
```

Comment: I've never seen this technique before I'll try it but not 100% sure whats going on I understand I can't pass variables into the function Could you show how to pass more than 1 variable?

Comment: I've linked some related questions. What do you mean by "*passing more than 1 variable*"?

Comment: i figured it out just took me a while to understand what I was lookin at.