# Control number showing max value

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I have a java script function that gets a string that represents a number, loops and returns the same value (max value) inside jquery function:

```
            function auto_tag_posts(data) {
                //data is 999
                var p_nr=0;
                for (p_nr=0; p_nr<data; p_nr++) {
                    $.post("./myphp.php", {command: "c"}, function(post_data){
                        //p_nr is 999!!! WHY?
                        alert(p_nr);
                    }); 
                }
```

What's the fix?

The problem was that there were made 999 requests in a split second, the answers were coming in time, but the jquery "for" was finished instantly.

Comment: You should really convert `data` to a number before.

Comment: You realize you're making 999 posts to the server

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript for loop unexpected behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170589/javascript-for-loop-unexpected-behaviour)

Answer (score 3):

That's because of closures. Use these c0dez instead

```
for (p_nr=0; p_nr<data; p_nr++) {
    (function(p_nr) {}
        $.post("./myphp.php", {command: "c"}, function(post_data){
            //p_nr is 999!!! WHY?
            alert(p_nr);
        }); 
    )(p_nr);
}
```